# The Delete data binding setting is required by the delete command. Please specify the Delete action or url in the DataBinding configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have added delete button on kendo and now am trying to delete and am getting the error below.

The Delete data binding setting is required by the delete command. 
Please specify the Delete action or url in the DataBinding configuration

```
            <div class="form-group">
                                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(dataList)
    .Name("MyGrid")
    .Columns(column =>
    {

column.Bound(c => c.PartId).Width("70px").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "vertical-align:top !important;" }).FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });
column.Bound(c => c.GMarkPartNumber)

    .Title("GM Part No").Width("90px").FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });
column.Bound(c => c.Description).FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });

column.Group(grp => grp
    .Title("Price")
    .Columns(info =>
    {


        info.Bound(x => x.Price).FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });
        info.Bound(x => x.Fitting).FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });
        info.Bound(x => x.Extras).FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });
        info.Bound(x => x.VAT).FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "display:none;" });
        info.Bound(x => x.TotalInc).FooterTemplate("<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-md-4 pull-right\"><div class=\"pull-right\">" +
            "<table><tr><td class=\"formatFooter\">Total Exclusive:</td><td class=\"formatFooter\">R" + data.totalExclusive + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td class=\"formatFooter\">Total VAT:</td><td class=\"formatFooter\">R" + data.totalVat + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td class=\"formatFooter\">Total Inclusive:</td><td class=\"formatFooter\">R" + data.totalInclusive + "</td></tr></table></div></div></div>")
                .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { colspan = 8 });


    }));
                                    column.Command(x => x.Destroy());
               })
                                       .Groupable()
                                    .Scrollable()
                                    .Sortable()

                                    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
                                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Server()

                                    ));
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your configuration of the datasource you need to add a statement like this (if using ajax):

```
.DataSource(ds =>{ 
                   ds.Ajax()
                     .Create(create => create.Action(....))
                     .Read(read => read.Action(....))
                     .Update(update => update.Action(....))
                     .Delete(delete => 
                             delete.Action("action","controller","{area if required}"));
                 }
           );
```

If you want to handle the delete mechanics manually then you will need to add on a custom delete button and then configure it in the way you need it to work.

If you need this expanding let me know and I will add more detail if required.

**EDIT**

If you are using the datasource.Server() implementation from your code sample just add on the method .Destroy("action", "controller", "route values")

e.g. change

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Server())
```

to

```
 .DataSource(data => data.Server().Destroy("action", "controller", new {area ="route options if required"}))
```

This should allow the delete button to work.

Comment: I only want to delete. i won't any button in future. only delete

Comment: Just add the the delete command to the datasource then. I showed the create, read, update purely for completeness.

Comment: I cannot get delete(it says it doesn't exist). how can i add delete command? please guide me

Comment: I have updated my answer with an edit based more on your use of the datasource configuration.

Comment: How must the action looks likes on the controller. i have no idea on how i can delete or disable. I have created a function called Remove() . How to delete or disable?